# Gaussian Norms problem if and only if

Tags: number-theory

**Problem:**

> Suppose $p$ is a prime number.
>
> Prove that $p$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{−5}]$ if and only if there does not exist $\alpha \in \Bbb Z[\sqrt{−5}]$ such that $N(\alpha) = p$.
>
> Using this, find the smallest prime number that is not irreducible in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{−5}]$.

**Known:**

\begin{gather*}
\alpha = a+b\sqrt{−5} \in \Bbb Z[\sqrt{−5}] \\[0.5ex]
N(\alpha) = a^2 + 5b^2 \\[0.5ex]
N(\alpha)N(\beta) = N(\alpha\beta)
\end{gather*}

**Attempt:*

I did $\implies$ so I'm now doing $\impliedby$.

(Contraposition)

Suppose that $p$ is reducible in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{−5}]$ and isn't prime. Then we know that $p$ can be a product of two numbers: call them $x,y \in \Bbb Z[\sqrt{−5}]$. Then we get that $N(P)=n(x,y)=n(x)n(y)=(a^2+5b^2)(c^2+5d^2)$.

Then I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Is there some specification regarding $\alpha$?

Comment: I think I just realized what your confusion might be. In the proof you suppose $p$ isn't prime. That's probably wrong, depending on what you mean by prime. But usually one understands primality as that of $\mathbb Z$. What you want to assume is that this prime splits in ${\mathbb Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $p \in \mathbb Z$ we have $N(p) = p^2$. Since $xy$ is a non-trivial factorization, neither $x$ nor $y$ is a unit, so neither $N(x)$ nor $N(y)$ equals $1$. It follows that $N(x) = N(y) = p$ and we are done.